# UIDatePicker wrong time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker. I select 2:30 AM, it passes me date with time 6:30AM. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Here's the code:

```
_datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolBar.frame.size.height, vcSize.width, 0)];
_datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
[_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
_datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
_datePicker.calendar = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
```

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Who knows? We can't read your mind. Post some code (but I suspect it has to do with time zones).

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue you are facing about the time zones
[UIDatePicker bug in iOS 4](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52533-uidatepicker-bug-ios-4-a.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
you  can select the date in to datePicker:

NSDate *date =  self.datePicker.date;
```

and you select any date in to datepicker will display the label:

```
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 160, 340, 300)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(LabelChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

-(void)LabelChange:(id)sender
{

 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];


if ([datePicker.date isEqualToDate:datePicker.date]) 
{
    NSLog(@"datePicker......");
}

[df release];

}
```

Comment: Please provide some details about what this code does, and why.

Comment: I am not trying to format a date. I am trying to get correct date. In other words, If I chose in the picker 10:50, it should give me 10:50. NSDateFormatter has nothing to do with this question. Please ready my question again.